# express middleware not calling

Tags: node.js, express

I try to call middleware from express router but i can not call middleware. may be i don't understand how to pass middleware to route here, any idea

```
in server.ts file, routes are registered

const app = express();
(new TestRoute()).register(app);

in route.ts file, we have route

public register(app: Express) {
        app.route('/:type/search')
            .options(this._optionsRoute.bind(this))
            .get(checkCache, this._handleRequest.bind(this));
    }

handle request like this
private _handleRequest(req: Request, res: Response) {....}

i have middleware like this

const checkCache = (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {....}
```

Comment: check this [article](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

Comment: Register your middleware methods with `app.use()` before you register your routes. Registration order matters to express.

Comment: yes, i register middleware before register ```app.use(checkCache)``` now it's calling

Comment: middleware checking before route calling with indefinite loop